# Compatibility range mismatch between web server and content database

Tags: 2010, backup

What could be the solution for this? I am performing a backup of a web application but it doesn't allow me and at last I end up with the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard so that it will upgrade the content DB to match with the SharePoint binaries' version. SharePoint will work to a certain point when there is a difference in DB vs. binaries version, but at some point the difference is too much and DB is blocked.

Alternative to SharePoint Config Wizard is to run:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait
```

It does exactly the same as the graphical SharePoint Configuration Wizard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Let me run the Configuration Wizard and get back to you.